# Batch listener in spring kafka 1.0.6 or kafka-client - 0.9.1

Tags: spring-kafka

I see batch listeners are supported 1.1.RELEASE onwards,

Is it possible to receive batch of records in version 1.0.6.RELEASE. Our kafka servers are still on kafka-clients-0.9.1, therefore cannot upgrade clients till servers are upgraded.

```
 @KafkaListener(id = "batch-listener", topics = "${kafka.topic.name}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void receive(ConsumerRecords<String, String> eventList) {}
```

Tried the above code, but it is failing on MessageConversionException while converting String to ConsumerRecord

Answer (score 0):

Batch listeners were added in 1.1.x; not available in 1.0.x.

Note that the batch listener receives a `List<ConsumerRecord<?,?>>` not a `ConsumerRecords`.